# Spring Boot and Security Dynamic Authentication and Authorization

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-acl

I am going to develop a login page using spring boot and security which users and roles can be created by admin so the system can have many roles and users...also admin can assign the roles to users and remove them as well.
I have used good samples of how to implement it but after reading so much doc and tutorials still having below questions and don't know what is the best practice to implement spring security and boot together.tried to move on debug mode to find out what is happening behind the scene step by step.

my assumption was for each and every http request application refers to WebSecurityConfig class to check the access but surprisingly it was not like that and fellow was as below.seems application goes to config class once at the beginning and every things populates.bootstrap doing so many actions in background and it made me confuse and can't understand the relation between the classes.

configureGlobal-->configure-->whatever you write as a URL it goes to /login) -->controller (login method) --> submit the form with user/pass --> loadUserByUsername --> controller (welcome method) --> welcome.jsp

1-what exactly configureGlobal and configure do when the application **loads**?

2-what is the exact role of AuthenticationManagerBuilder?

3-how spring security knows to send the user/pass after form submition to loadUserByUsername method?

4-loadUserByUsername return user object to where? because when methods reach to the end it redirects to controller welcome method and it send you to welcome method when username and password is correct.

4-how to use grantedAuthorities to re-direct the user based on his role to different pages?

```html
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>

<c:set var="contextPath" value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}"/>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Log in with your account</title>

    <link href="${contextPath}/resources/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="${contextPath}/resources/css/common.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>

<body>

<div class="container">

    <form method="POST" action="${contextPath}/login" class="form-signin">
        <h2 class="form-heading">Log in</h2>
        <div class="form-group ${error != null ? 'has-error' : ''}">
            <span>${message}</span>
            <input name="username" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username"
                   autofocus="true"/>
            <input name="password" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password"/>
            <span>${error}</span>
            <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>

            <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Log In</button>
            <h4 class="text-center"><a href="${contextPath}/registration">Create an account</a></h4>
        </div>
    </form>

</div>
<!-- /container -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="${contextPath}/resources/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**WebSecurityConfig Class**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

@Bean
public BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/resources/**", "/registration").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login").permitAll()
                .and()
            .logout().permitAll();

}

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder());
}
}
```

**UserDetailsServiceImpl class**

```
@Service
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService{

@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepository;

@Override
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

    User user = userRepository.findByUsername(username);

    Set<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = new HashSet<>();

    for (Role role : user.getRoles()){
        grantedAuthorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getName()));
    }

    return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), grantedAuthorities);

}
}
```

**UserController Class**

```
@Controller
public class UserController {
@Autowired
private UserService userService;

@Autowired
private SecurityService securityService;

@Autowired
private UserValidator userValidator;

@RequestMapping(value = "/registration", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String registration(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("userForm", new User());

    return "registration";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/registration", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String registration(@ModelAttribute("userForm") User userForm, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model) {

    userValidator.validate(userForm, bindingResult);

    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        return "registration";
    }

    userService.save(userForm);

    securityService.autologin(userForm.getUsername(), userForm.getPasswordConfirm());

    return "redirect:/welcome";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String login(Model model, String error, String logout) {
    if (error != null)
        model.addAttribute("error", "Your username and password is invalid.");

    if (logout != null)
        model.addAttribute("message", "You have been logged out successfully.");

    return "login";
}

@RequestMapping(value = {"/", "/welcome"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String welcome(Model model) {
    return "welcome";
}


}
```

Comment: Peter, your question is too broad. Be more specific in the problem you are having, show what you tried and ask one question at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to share the answer of some questions which are clear to me now.

1. when you start your project , first of all it goes to **WebSecurityConfig** class and look for **configureGlobal** method to build the authentication process and then looks for **configure** method to set the security.
2. **AuthenticationManagerBuilder** is a class with many methods like **userDetailsService** which is used to authenticate based on user details so when you login it will sends the credentails to a class which has implemented **UserDetailsService** interface.
3. A POST to the **/login** URL will attempt to authenticate the user so configureGlobal will do the needful.
4. It has called from **configureGlobal** method and is returned backed there and still everything is in root path so will find the proper method in controller class.
5. **AuthenticationSuccessHandler** can help in this regard.